# Как сделать подобный фон на сайте?

Tags: css

CSS знаю средненько.
На сайте [allods.ru](http://allods.ru/) увидел интересное поведение фона. Захотелось понять как оно сделано, но понять не удалось...      
Может кто набросать **html** и **CSS**?    
Заранее спасибо!

Я имею ввиду **фон**. Он состоит из 4-х **картинок**. Они центрируются по вертикале, причем первые две прижаты к верху страницы, нижние две к низу страницы.

Comment: Если вы про шапку - это флеш.

Comment: когда к body  применяешь, оба не работают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#main-right-bottom-bg {#правая картинка внизу
background: url('/images/bg/картинка1.jpg') left bottom no-repeat;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
bottom: 0;
width: 50%;
height: 1225px;
z-index: 2;
}
#main-left-bottom-bg {#левая картинка внизу
background: url('/images/bg/картинка2.jpg') right bottom no-repeat;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 50%;
height: 1225px;
z-index: 2;
}

ну а потом объявить
<div id="main-left-bottom-bg"></div>
<div id="main-right-bottom-bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы имеете ввиду что? Анимацию маленькую? Дык это флеш. Еще что-то? Скажите поподробнее - я вам расскажу.

http://allods.mail.ru/media/css/main.css?v=10
секция #main-left-top-bg и ниже

Общий смысл: берется таблица во всю ширину и высоту (4 штуки), и накладываются друг на друга слоями посредством z-index, а у каждой - свой бэкграунд смещенный, куда надо и неповторяемый.